# Blazor app on Azure Web App shares user specific infos to all instances

Tags: azure, caching, blazor, azure-web-app-service, blazor-webassembly

To be honest: It is my first Blazor app!
I have an blazor app, which is the UI for an Azure Open AI using Azure bot. The blazor app is using standard bot client to send and receive data from the Open AI on Azure based bot. This all runs great in the dev environment.
I can publish the app via an action from GitHub into an Azure Web App (Not static Web App!).
I can also lauch the web app through the normal URL and it works.
I close the browser and shut down my PC.
Another user is lauching the standard URL or the web app and can see directly my last chat.
I do the same with a different browser (Edge instead of Chrome)...same result.
I added the following to my project file to deactivate caching:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <BlazorCacheBootResources>false</BlazorCacheBootResources>
</PropertyGroup>
```

No changes

I added the following in the Azure portal at my web app to overwrite the header for chaching. No changes at all.Added this into appsettings (Azure portal):

```
WEBSITE_HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL = no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

What I want is thte EVERYTIME me or any user is opening a new browser or tab the app should start with the homepage and no chanced data. So to say from scratch.

Thanks a lot in advance
Ricardo

Comment: You have tagged [blazor-webassembly] but I suspect it is a blazor-server app. Anyway, either in the App or in the API you have some crucial data `static` or Singleton.

Comment: @HH ℍ ℍ was completely right. I had static variables in the code, which I removed and after that all was fine.Thanks a lot for your help.
Unfortunately you just commented therefore I was not able to make the answer as solution